# Why do Javascript projects check built results in to git?

Tags: javascript, git

I've been using git for 10 years or more. Recently started working in javascript, and I notice lots of module (npm) projects check their build results into the repo! That seems totally backward to me. Doesn't it make it harder to contribute to them, because you always look like you have modified files that shouldn't be committed back as part of your PR?

I see at least vue.js and three.js but I've seen many others. I always figured you clone from github and do a build step -- I guess it makes it simpler for users who just want to clone & go? Seems like a waste though, and I figured that's what npm is for.

Comment: The build is included so users can `npm install` packages and not have to worry about a build phase.

Comment: I completely agree. If you want an env with npm modules pre-installed, then you should use a container ( ex: docker ) to provide this.

If you're seeing a node_modules folder in a git repo, that'd be very bad practice.

Comment: So backwards. I assumed people would do something like this article: https://medium.com/dailyjs/building-a-react-component-with-webpack-publish-to-npm-deploy-to-github-guide-6927f60b3220 where they add a build step they run before doing `npm publish`, which then ignores everything except `dist`.

Comment: @StevenStark I'm not talking about `node_modules`, just the built (webpack or babel) `dist` or `built` folder. Still seems like bad practice to me, but what do I know.

Comment: @GaryO sorry, I must have misread, however IMO those all fall in the same camp to me. I would not include build, dist, or any other items into a repo unless there was a specific need.

Answer (score 1):

**The intended consumer isn't *necessarily* using npm.**

Both [three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene) and [vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include) can be consumed in ways that don't involve a build step. Instead, consumers can include the library by including it with a `<script>` tag. By publishing an official compiled build, they're allowing integrators to download it from Github instead of having to build it from source themselves.

If I needed to build Vue from source, I'd probably succeed, but it'd take a non-zero amount of work and I'd be less confident in the result. Look at all the build scripts they define in their [package.json](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/package.json) file. Do I need to run `release`? or `release:weex`? I'd probably have to run both and compare the output. This is annoying and I'd feel much better just downloading something they provided.

---

I've also dealt with some *bad* reasons to do this.

1. I've worked with a few acquaintances that weren't familiar with npm that think projects should Just Work out of the box without additional build steps.
2. Office politics - I've personally dealt with this - my colleagues were working on an npm based project and weren't able to get npm or node installed on our build server. The build server's gatekeeper wouldn't install them without getting an official blessing from our sercurity team. The security wasn't willing to prioritize reviewing it and our build pipeline required *something* in git to deploy our code. We opted to commit the compiled code.

Comment: _Publishing_ a build makes perfect sense, I totally agree. Even publishing it to a (different) github repo perhaps you could make a case for (treating github like a CDN). But I don't get why people publish it _as part of the source_. It makes contributing much more of a pain -- I expect even for the original authors/maintainers.

Comment: To follow up, I see both three.js and vue.js only update their builds periodically (makes sense). So if you fork and clone, then do a build, your repo now always looks dirty (has modified files) even before you changed anything! And when you do commit, you have to remember to not add the build/dist tree. It just doesn't make sense to me. Oh well.

Comment: I'm inclined to think of it as releases. IMO, putting it in the source makes for an easily accessible way to find a previous build without having a documentation page dedicated to it. You'd just have to find the right tag on Github.

You've mentioned a tradeoff of having messy modified files in a `git diff` - isn't that mitigated by including the dist directory in a `.gitignore` file (I don't use git directly on the command line enough to know off hand)?

Comment: Putting it in `.gitignore` _would_ indeed be better... But of course then creating builds would be more difficult because it's a pain to add and commit gitignored files. I've thought about how I (and other contributors) could add a ".gitignore.local" somehow, to hide these -- so `git commit -am'My contribution"` would work as expected, but I don't have an answer to that yet. (Similarly w/ any git gui -- "add all modified files" will add your build/dist.)

Comment: BTW the usual answer to this (at least the "dirty git files" part) is to use `git update-index --skip-worktree dist` which does help, until you do a pull -- then it says both sides have modifications and you have to resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The final build for JavaScript projects is usually smaller than the source code and doesn't take up much space in the version control system. Projects that build to binaries are usually massive compared to the source code and checking in the build would bloat the space needed for the repository.

That being said I think that the build should not be checked in.